# ActionScript 3.0 Load PDF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I am trying to load a PDF into my Adobe Air Application using ActionScript, On my machine I have the latest Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and Adobe Acrobat XI Pro.

I have been following these steps on this tutorial: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7eb4.html

but I am stuck here:

```
if(HTMLLoader.pdfCapability == HTMLPDFCapability.STATUS_OK)  
{ 
    trace("PDF content can be displayed"); 
} 
else  
{ 
    trace("PDF cannot be displayed. Error code:", HTMLLoader.pdfCapability); 
}
```

but it keeps saying PDF cannot be displayed. Error code: 3204 which is An error was returned by the OS when trying to load the Adobe Reader or Acrobat application or one of its necessary libraries.

Am I missing something here? Or don't have something installed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMLLoader is a bit outdated, that's why its no longer compatible with recent versions of Adobe Reader, I suggest using StageWebView instead. You will be able to display the PDF in your app, not communicate with it.

```
private function loadPDF():void
{       
    var myStageWebView:StageWebView = new StageWebView(true);
    myStageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0 , 0, 300, 300);
    myStageWebView.stage = this.stage;
    myStageWebView.loadURL("http://www.example.com/book.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Do I have to import something?

Comment: Also I dont want to load a PDF from the web either.

Comment: Yes, you only require the StageWebView class, it is included in the AIR SDK, your IDE will detect it and import it for you.

You can load PDF's from the file system, you will only require to do something like this:


var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("book.pdf");
myStageWebView.loadURL(file.url);